# Installing LuxRender engine changes the appearance of the Cycles render engine

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, node-editor, luxrender-render-engine

Is it possible that since I installed **LuxRender 1.5** on Blender 2.76 yesterday, **Cycles** has stopped to display its GUI as it used to?

Here is the behavior I am used to:

*-create new scene
-switch to Cycles Render
-in the Materials Panel, enable Nodes for the selected object (default cube)
-Nodes appear in the Node Editor for said object (Shader Nodes is the Default Node view displayed) *

Here is the behavior since today:

*-create new scene

-switch to Cycles Render

-in the Materials Panel, enable Nodes for the selected object (default cube)

-Shader Nodes don't appear in the Node Editor for said object, as Compositor Nodes are the Default selection*

It does seem like default settings for the display have been corrupted or changed inside Cycles since I installed LuxRender.

**Screenshot of the issue** (taken right after enabling Nodes for the object):
[image]
*(this is with the blender version where LuxRender is installed)*

**Expected behavior** (taken after following identical steps):
[image]
*(this was produced on a brand new version of blender 2.77 installed on the same machine, and with the same result on another machine with a "clean" version of 2.76)*

Blend file (requires LuxRender 1.5 and Blender 2.76b to reproduce the bug):

[image]

Comment: You're in the compositing nodes, click on the materials tab( two to the right). Does that take care of it?

Comment: Ok, good point. Still, the thing that happened is that installing LuxRender has corrupted the GUI/display of Cycles in the way that the order of the Node Tree types buttons is displayed in the Node Editor. Compositing / Texture / Shader in my corrupt version, Shader / Compositing / Texture in fresh installs. This is still worrisome, as I have no idea what else has changed (that is visible or not), and since I rely on muscle memory a lot...

Comment: I have edited the question to reflect @Timaroberts ' comment.

Comment: I've noticed that those node tree type buttons seem to get switched around a lot.. Between different blender versions, addons which add node tree types, etc. Hopefully that part of the interface will get a re-examination with the 2.8 nodify-everything project

Comment: @gandalf3 this is the closest thing to an answer, turn it into an answer if you can. Kind of afraid of what "nodify everything" could mean for the next big release, but we'll see I guess !

Comment: @Timaroberts can you make it an answer to allow me to accept and close it?